# Converting date to hour and minute format in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to convert the current date (in groovy)

```
 def currentDate= new Date() 
 println currentDate
 Tue Dec 30 14:48:00 EST 2014
```

into (that is hour and minute format) `1448` or `14:48`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`Date.format`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format%28java.lang.String%29):

```
new Date().format('HHmm')
new Date().format('HH:mm')
```

Comment: @elyon: is that what You were looking for?

Comment: how do i get current day of the week from the current date...something like 'Tue Dec 30 14:48:00 EST 2014' = Tue

Comment: `new Date().format('EEE')` - see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html